# Counting transactions on 2 different levels

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google Analytics data in BigQuery, my desired output is

```
USERID    INTERACTIONS   TRANSACTIONS    SCORE    CHANNEL
XXX       3              1               33.33    Paid
```

Below is my query so far - I am getting duplicate transactions and I can;t work out why, Unesting my hits led to a high count of `interactions` as every line was bring counted, so I added the `AND hit.isentrance IS TRUE` clause, which means I can't use `COUNT( DISTINCT hit.transaction.transactionid)` as the entry row will never contain an order ID - instead I have to use totals.transactions, which I where I think my issues could be coming from?

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Campaign_Interactions) AS Interactions, SUM(Transactions) AS Transactions, ROUND(SUM(Transactions)/SUM(Campaign_Interactions), 2) AS Con_Score, MasterChannel FROM(
(SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID, visitid AS visitid1, trafficSource.campaign AS Campaign, COUNT(trafficSource.campaign) AS Campaign_Interactions, SUM (totals.transactions) AS Transactions, ROUND(MAX(totals.transactions)/COUNT(trafficSource.campaign), 2) AS Conversion_Score
FROM `xxx.ga_sessions_20*` AS m
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(m.customdimensions) AS customDimension
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits) AS hit
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 7 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
AND customDimension.index = 2
AND trafficSource.campaign IS NOT NULL
AND (customDimension.value NOT LIKE 'true' AND customDimension.value NOT LIKE 'undefined')
AND hit.isentrance IS TRUE
GROUP BY visitid1, Campaign, userID
ORDER BY Transactions DESC)

JOIN

(SELECT * FROM `xxx.7Days_VisitID_MasterChan`)
ON visitid1 = visitid)
GROUP BY UserID, MasterChannel
ORDER BY UserID
```

And a screenshot of results. Note that for the ID 00004180-16f5-46e4-9caa-c6b47e03d795 (near the bottom) there should be only 1 order, but we are seeing it on each row.

It's fine for the user to have interactions across multiple channels, this is expected. Multiple transactions across multiple channels is also fine, but I can see in our CRM that this UserID has made only one order in the last 7 days, so I'd only expect to see a single transaction against the ID here.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the results from when you run the query above?

Comment: Also, the aggregate SUM (totals.transactions) seems to be using a table that is not bound in your query. Where do you reference totals?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the results above - totals.transactions is a field within ga_sessions_

Comment: K, the results indicate that one user belongs to multiple channels. Are you saying that is not the case, or should not be the case?

Comment: It's fine for the user to have interactions across multiple channels, this is expected. Multiple transactions across multiple channels is also fine, but I can see in our CRM that this UserID has made only one order in the last 7 days, so I'd only expect to see a single transaction against the ID here.

Comment: In which dataset would the order made by this user be recorded ?

Comment: For this query it is recorded in the _ga_sessions_ table - I can reference the actual orders in our transactional DB, but I cannot query this DB and it doesn't contain the actual onsite activity.

Comment: It is hard to read this query without an alias and prefix for your table and fields. It is impossible to tell which tables the fields are coming from. However, I bet that last JOIN on xxx.7Days_VisitID_MasterChan is going to have 4 records for the user ending in 95. Even though the user did not purchase at all 5, there was a visit. When you overlay the Tx with this, the 1 purchase will fall against all 5 visits.